# How to plot three coordinates in function of a fourth (3 positional coordinates in function of time) in R?

Tags: r, 3d, 4d, iplots

I would like to plot a 4 dimensional graph in R. I have three coordinates of position and a fourth variable (time). In this plot I would like to show these 3 coordinates in function of time. I only have one observation for each coordinate in each time. Somebody know if this is possible in R? I only found solutions for 3D plots.

For example:

```
coord_1<-c(0.5,0.3,0.9)
coord_2<-c(0.2,0.1,0.6)
coord_3<-c(0.7,0.4,0.8)
time_seg<-c(0.1,0.5,1)

data_plot<-data.frame(coord_1,coord_2,coord_3, time_seg)
data_plot

coord_1 coord_2 coord_3 time_seg
1     0.5     0.2     0.7      0.1
2     0.3     0.1     0.4      0.5
3     0.9     0.6     0.8      1.0
```

Comment: Have you looked into animated charts that can plot coordinates in 3 dimensions?  If I recall correctly, I think package `googleVis` offers some functionality in that way, though I may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you Raphael,

I read the manual of googleVis. However, the coordinates which I have don't are geographical coordinates. These coordinates are position in a 3d space. Apparently, googleVis only work with informations of Google Maps.

Comment: I would use the `scatterplot3d` package and the `animation` package.

Comment: Gregor,

I tried to use these two packages. However, dont know how insert a fourth axis in the plot. I need a axis for the variable time (not a gradient of color, such as the scatterplot3d package shows as the fouth variable) and other three for the coordinates. Do you know how it could be possible?

Comment: I thought you wanted your forth dimension to *literally* be time, via the animate package. If that's not what you mean then I don't know what you're trying to do. Do you have an example of a 4d plot that you'd like to emulate?

Comment: Gregor, I am trying to representate the head movements over time. So, I measured three coordinates positions in a 3D space for a period of time. This way, for each second, for example, I have one value for each coordinate. Actually, I want one x-axis (for time) and three Y-axis (one for each coordinate). With this plot I will be able to observe the head movents across the time.

Comment: I've never seen a readable 4-d plot. Do you have an example of one?